# Objective C Display Multiple Sets of Info from JSON

Tags: php, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I have the following php page that is sending JSON encoded info through a web service:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$arr = array(
    0 =>
        array(
            'userName'=>'user1',
            'userBio'=>'This is user1 bio.',
            'userSubmitted'=>15
        ),
    1 =>
        array(
            'userName'=>'user2',
            'userBio'=>'This is user2 bio.',
            'userSubmitted'=>2
        ),
    2 =>
        array(
            'userName'=>'user3',
            'userBio'=>'This is user3 bio.',
            'userSubmitted'=>7
        ),
);

echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

I am trying to have our app display each set of user information, but right now only the last set of information is showing.  What's the appropriate code to display all sets and not just the last set of information?  Here is the Objective C code:

```
NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://domain.com/json2.php"];
NSData *myData1 = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
NSError *error1;
NSArray *users = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData1 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error1];


if(!error1)
{
    for (NSDictionary * user in users)
    {
        textUser.text = [user objectForKey: @"userName"];

        textBio.text = [user objectForKey: @"userBio"];

        textSubmitted.text = [user objectForKey: @"userSubmitted"];
    }
}

else
{
    textUser.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error--%@",[error1 description]];
}
```

Comment: textUser.text,textBio.text,textSubmitted.text if you showing getting data on labels very data is replacing with new data .that's why it showing new data that means last  arrival  data

Comment: Ok I understand how that works.  Do you know what a solution would be to get all 3 sets to display at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display all the sets, you can create a single string containing all the information and then assign it to a single label. Instead of using three separate labels. i.e., create a single `UILabel` say `allUsersInfo`.
 Then use the following code:

```
NSString *userName = [NSString string];
NSString *userBio = [NSString string];
NSString *userSubmitted = [NSString string];
for (NSDictionary * user in users)
{
    userName = [user objectForKey: @"userName"];
    userBio = [user objectForKey: @"userBio"];
    userSubmitted = [user objectForKey: @"userSubmitted"];
    allUsersInfo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@\n\n",userName,userBio,userSubmitted];
}
```

Hope this helps!